# Fulltext match() against() returning empty set

Tags: mysql, indexing, full-text-indexing

I have a full text indexed table set up with the data Family in it.  There is no White Space and the spelling is correct.  How can I make this query match results as score and display them by score in DESC order? I keep getting empty set and don't know why.

```
 SELECT *, MATCH(MEDIA_TITLE) AGAINST('Family') AS SCORE FROM MEDIA_DATA_VIDS WHERE MATCH(MEDIA_TITLE) AGAINST('Family') ORDER BY SCORE DESC ;
```

Any Help is Greatly Appreciated.

Comment: Did you read on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-natural-language.html: `The search result is empty because the word “MySQL” is present in at least 50% of the rows, and so is effectively treated as a stopword.`

Comment: Ok so if i have more entries without the search term, less than 50% it should work? other words beside "Family" right?

Comment: Yep, that's the idea. Unless you pick another stop word.

Comment: Post this as an answer it helped me a lot, might help someone else, and Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-natural-language.html:

> The search result is empty because the word “MySQL” is present in at least 50% of the rows, and so is effectively treated as a stopword.

So you need to search for a different word. But don't pick another stop word.