# How to perform Full-Text Search in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a database table that I output on a website with a search field for each column and one global search field.

Im trying to figure out how to create a dynamic search in the global search field that combines the strings i add from all the columns. Is this possible?

My current query below.

```
  SELECT flexstock.`SKU`,
           flexstock.`Partnr`,
           flexstock.`Manufacturer`,
           flexstock.`Description`,
           flexstock.`Status`,
           flexstock.`QTY`
    FROM flexstock
```

Comment: Have you read [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html) for full-text searches?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search in all fields from every table of a MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639531/search-in-all-fields-from-every-table-of-a-mysql-database)

Comment: I had a similar question not to long ago. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49072765/fulltext-match-against-returning-empty-set